# Unable to make array of arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, jagged-arrays

I need to make a JS array like

```
var locations = [
            ['Erbil, Soran POS', 36.649415, 44.534143, 4],
            ['Duhok, Duhok', 36.867905, 42.948857, 4],
            ['Duhok, Akre', 36.700016, 43.920457, 4],
            ['Duhok, Zakho', 37.150462, 42.672677, 4],
            ['Duhok, Shiladze', 36.650648, 44.519263, 4],
            ['Duhok, Bardaresh', 36.650648, 44.519263, 4],
            ['Mosel, Sinjar', 36.314216, 41.862443, 4],
            ['Duhok, Duhok', 36.867905, 42.948857, 4],
            ['Duhok, Akre', 36.741121, 43.880849, 4],
            ['Duhok, Zakho', 37.150462, 42.672677, 4],
            ['Duhok, Shiladze', 36.650648, 44.519263, 4],
            ['Duhok, Bardaresh', 36.911505, 42.728491, 4],
            ['Duhok, Amadia', 37.091727, 43.487692, 4],
            ['Sulimanya, Sulimanya', 35.557045, 45.435943, 4],
            ['Sulimanya, Dirbendikan', 35.110939, 45.695271, 4],
    ];
```

I am trying like this:

```
var locations;
for (i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
    locations = new Array(searchResults[i].name, searchResults[i].latitude, searchResults[i].longtitude, searchResults[i].zm);
    searchLocations.push(locations)
}
```

But its making an array that has data but its length is '0' and hence I can't use for loop etc.

Please tell what wrong am I doing?

Comment: where is `searchLocations` defined ?

Comment: the `searchLocations` is being returned from a db result and can be successfully called as `searchResults[i].name`, `searchResults[i].latitude`, `searchResults[i].longtitude`, `searchResults[i].zm`.

its just that running `console.log(searchLocations.length);` gives `0`.

Comment: can you edit your question and post searchResults?

Comment: I can do a simple 
console.log(searchResults);
its result is like

`>[Object, Object, Object, Object]
  >0:Object
  >1:Object
       name:"Duhok"
       latitude:"36.700016"
       longtitude:"43.9204"
       zm:"4address"
       pho: ""
   >__prototype__: Object`

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some hit and trials I managed to this by the following way.

```
searchResults = data.data;//data from DB
//console.log(searchResults);
var locations = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
locations[i] = [searchResults[i].name, searchResults[i].latitude, searchResults[i].longtitude, searchResults[i].zm];
 }
```

This made the exact same array like I needed

```
[
        ['Duhok, Duhok', 36.867905, 42.948857, 4],
        ['Sulimanya, Sulimanya', 35.557045, 45.435943, 4],
        ['Sulimanya, Dirbendikan', 35.110939, 45.695271, 4],
];
```

Hope this helps others too who get into this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following

```
var searchLocations=[];
for (i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
    var locations = new Array(searchResults[i].name, searchResults[i].latitude, searchResults[i].longtitude, searchResults[i].zm);
    searchLocations.push(locations)
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat the same as my question, and the fact that I have tried it, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @MShoaibQureshi I have tried using demo data provided by you and it's working completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
for (i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
  var locations = [];
  locations.push(searchResults[i].name);
  location.push(searchResults[i].latitude);
  location.push(searchResults[i].longtitude);
  location.push(searchResults[i].zm)
  searchLocations.push(locations)
}
```

Comment: Used this but this also gives zero length for `console.log(searchLocations.length);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate over each item of an array, that creates a new array with the returned values.

We are also using object destructuring to pull the keys out of the object creating local variables within the callback function.

**es6**

```js
const searchResults = [
  { name: 'Erbil, Soran POS', latitude: 36.649415, longitude: 44.534143, zm: 4 },
  { name: 'Duhok, Duhok', latitude: 36.867905, longitude: 42.948857, zm: 4 },
  { name: 'Duhok, Akre', latitude: 36.700016, longitude: 43.920457, zm: 4 },
]

const searchLocations = searchResults.map(({ name, latitude, longitude, zm }) => ([
  name,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  zm
]))

console.log(searchLocations)
```

**es5**

```js
var searchResults = [
  { name: 'Erbil, Soran POS', latitude: 36.649415, longitude: 44.534143, zm: 4 },
  { name: 'Duhok, Duhok', latitude: 36.867905, longitude: 42.948857, zm: 4 },
  { name: 'Duhok, Akre', latitude: 36.700016, longitude: 43.920457, zm: 4 }
]

var searchLocations = searchResults.map(function(location) {
  return [
    location.name,
    location.latitude,
    location.longitude,
    location.zm
  ]
})
  
console.log(searchLocations)
```

Answer (score 0):

After thoroughly reading your question, I've came to the conclusion, that this is might be what do you expect.

```js
var locations = [['Erbil, Soran POS', 36.649415, 44.534143, 4], ['Duhok, Duhok', 36.867905, 42.948857, 4], ['Duhok, Akre', 36.700016, 43.920457, 4], ['Duhok, Zakho', 37.150462, 42.672677, 4], ['Duhok, Shiladze', 36.650648, 44.519263, 4], ['Duhok, Bardaresh', 36.650648, 44.519263, 4], ['Mosel, Sinjar', 36.314216, 41.862443, 4], ['Duhok, Duhok', 36.867905, 42.948857, 4], ['Duhok, Akre', 36.741121, 43.880849, 4], ['Duhok, Zakho', 37.150462, 42.672677, 4], ['Duhok, Shiladze', 36.650648, 44.519263, 4], ['Duhok, Bardaresh', 36.911505, 42.728491, 4], ['Duhok, Amadia', 37.091727, 43.487692, 4], ['Sulimanya, Sulimanya', 35.557045, 45.435943, 4], ['Sulimanya, Dirbendikan', 35.110939, 45.695271, 4]],
    searchResults = [], i = 0, elems = ['name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'zm'];

    while (i < 4){
      var obj = {}, arr = [];
      locations.forEach(function(v){
        arr.push(v[i])
      });
      obj[elems[i]] = arr;
      searchResults.push(obj);
      i++
    }
    console.log(searchResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that your searchLocations has length property as 0, and you can't loop through it by `for (i = 0; i < i.length; i++)` since the condition always evaluates to false. However, you can access the the item of searchLocations by index.

Based on that I guess the searchLocations is an 'Array-like Object' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects, but not a native array. You can try to convert it to an array by `searchLocationsArray = Array.prototype.call(searchLocations)` and then loop through it.